# spring data save does only create cascaded children if parent did not exist

Tags: jpa, spring-data

I have the following Entities: `Question` has OneToOne `Config`. And `Config` has many `Option`s. All are configured to `CASCADE.ALL` (s. appendix)

Based on a `RequestDTO` (`requestConfig`) I create new `Option` entities with `id=null` for either a NEW question or an EXISTING question.

In both cases **I want to access the generated ids of the new `Options`.**. However, it does work for new questions, but not for existing ones:

**New Question** (OK)

```
// RequestDTO requestConfig is a controller parameter
Question question = new Question(...);
Config config = requestDTO.createConfig(Optional.empty());
question.setConfig(config);

LinkedHashMap<String, Option> idMapping = requestConfig.getNewOptions();

idMapping.forEach((foo, option) -> System.out.println(option.getId())); // all null

question = questionRepo.save(question);

idMapping.forEach((foo, option) -> System.out.println(option.getId())); // 675, 676, ... etc
```

**Existing Question** (Broken, see last line, ids are null)

```
// RequestDTO requestConfig is a controller parameter
Question question = questionRepo.find(...);
Config config = requestDTO.getConfig(Optional.of(question.getConfig()));
question.setConfig(config);

LinkedHashMap<String, Option> idMapping = requestConfig.getNewOptions();

idMapping.forEach((foo, option) -> System.out.println(option.getId())); // all null

question = questionRepo.save(question);

idMapping.forEach((foo, option) -> System.out.println(option.getId())); // all null
```

Why is this happening? I would expect the `LinkedHashMap` `idMapping` to contain the newly created `Option`s with their created ids since they were cascaded from the question save operation. I checked the DB and they are inserted!

---

**APPENDIX**

For reference, here is my `RequestDTO` and the entities:

```
public class RequestDTO {
    private LinkedHashMap<String, OptionDTO> optionDTOs;
    @JsonIgnore
    private LinkedHashMap<String, Option> newOptions = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public Config getConfig(Optional<Config> oldConfig) {
        Config config = new Config();
        if (oldConfig.isPresent()) {
            config = oldConfig.get();
        }
        // update the options based on our OptionDTOs
        config.getOptions().clear();
        optionDTOs.stream()
                .map(o -> {
                    try { // to find the existing option
                        Option theOption = config.getOptions().stream()
                                // try to find in given config
                                .filter(existing -> o.getId().equals(existing.getId()))
                                .findAny()
                                // fallback to db
                                .orElse(optionRepo.findOne(Long.parseLong(o.getId())));
                        if (null != theOption) {
                            return theOption;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    // handle as new one by creating a new one with id=null
                    Option newOption = new Option(null, config);
                    newOptions.add(newOption);
                    return newOption;
                })
                .forEach(o -> config.getOptions().add(o));
        return config;
    }
    // getters
}
```

**Entity: Question**

```
@Entity
public class Question {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "config_id", nullable = false)
    private Config config;

    // ...
}
```

**Entity: Config**

```
@Entity
public class Config {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "config")
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", nullable = true)
    private Question question;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "config", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Option> options = new ArrayList<>();
    // ...
}
```

**Entity: Option**

```
@Entity
public class Option {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "config_id", nullable = false)
    private Config config;

    public Option(Long id, Config config) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.config = config;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `questionRepo.save()` on a new `Question`, Spring Data recognizes that you're trying to save a new entity, and invokes `EntityManager.persist()` internally.

`EntityManager.persist(entity)` makes **the entity passed as the argument persistent**.

However, when you call `questionRepo.save()` on an existing `Question`, Spring Data invokes `EntityManager.merge()` internally.

`EntityManager.merge(entity)` returns **a persistent copy of the entity**.

The problem is that you call `requestConfig.getNewOptions()` *before* calling `questionRepo.save()`. It doesn't matter in the first case you've described, since the original instance assigned to `question` (i.e. the one created using `Question question = new Question(...);`), as well as the child instances added to `Option` using the line `.forEach(o -> config.getOptions().add(o))`, **become persistent**, and obtain an autogenerated id.

However, it **does** matter in the second case, since the new child instances added to `Option` using the line `.forEach(o -> config.getOptions().add(o))`, **do not become persistent**. Instead, only the child entity instaces referenced **by the copy** returned by `questionRepo.save()` (which in turn returns the result of `EntityManager.merge()`) are persistent.

You should simply construct the `idMapping` map *after* calling `questionRepo.save()` (using `question.getConfig().getNewOptions()`). That should handle both cases.

Comment: Thanks for your try! While your explanation makes more clear what the problem is, the suggested solution does not work: the `newOptions` field of the config is built before `save(...)` (when calling `requestDTO.getConfig(...)` and it cannot be done after `save` since part of the saving operation should be storing the new options. The `newOptions` field does hold `Option` objects with their ids being null.

Answer (score 0):

> I checked the DB and they are inserted!

This happens by the entityManager just return new id of the current entity and not the related entities saved by cascade. After save your question try to find again by the question id.