# How can I create parent entity only once, when multiple child are created in the hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have one User class and one Note class defined as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notes")
public class Note {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String title;
    @Column
    private String content;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

// getters and setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String userName;

 //getters and setters
}
```

I'm trying to create a "Note" and what I want to achieve is, as part of my request payload, I'll pass my user details, with id, as below:

```
[{
    "title": "Mynote",
    "content": "This is another note",
    "user": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "user_1",
        "userName": "S"
    }
}]
```

I want that, if "User" is already there it should not update the users table with new entry, and if user with given id is not there it should create a new one and link that one to the notes.

For this I used `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`, above `private User user` field in "Notes" class. 
It works for one request, but for next request it throws

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
   Duplicate entry '5' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

This is expected as it is trying to insert same row twice.

Can I achieve this using some annotation in spring or od I have to handle this in my own code as: while creating note, I have to check if the user exists or not and if it does not exist, then create a new one, and then save the note.

(Basically, this is what I want to achieve using hibernate/spring-data-jpa, if some support is there).

Comment: Please show the code of your repository. How do you save the user?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50634305/spring-data-save-does-only-create-cascaded-children-if-parent-did-not-exist check this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For more technical details, please take a look at the link provided by @Chinthaka Dinadasa under your question.

For a quick and easier solution, think of it from a different side. Let's add notes to a user and save this user (not note).

**User entity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) // !!! add "cascade" 
    private List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
```

**Note entity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "note_table")
public class Note {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
```

now if you try to call twice the following method in some `@Service`, you'll have one user and 2 notes for this user:

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void acceptNewNote() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(0L);
        Note note = new Note();
        user.setNotes(Arrays.asList(note));

        userRepository.save(user);
```

where **UserRepository** is:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>
```